# Excel 2010 cant print with collate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work in an environment with 150 windows computers. Most of them are with Windows 7 and XP. We use only Canon printers.

Before one week we experienced one problem printing from Windows 7 pro 64bit with all updates up to date, and trying to print to shared canon mf4410 printer with UFR II driver/no others from canon/. This first happen with one PC. When the user try to print from Excel 2010 with collate option enabled 2 or more copies, the printer print only page and then goes to Pause and cant be used until restart or delete the second page from the printer job status.

The biggest problem is that this issue is escalating into other Win 7 Pro machines with direct usb connection to Canon printers.

I tried with reinstalling printer drivers, latest, oldest, same problem. As far as i can understand from all that mess is that the problem is somewhere with Windows 7. Because this is happen only with Win 7 computers that print to UFR II drivers. With Xp i dont have any problems. And this is happer with MS Office 2010 only.

When i try with uncollate, the printer print many copies. For now this is the only working sollution. And only if it is changed from Excel, not from the driver.

I try installing other printer and print only with PCL drivers.

Can someone give other directions that i can try?

Comment: Try to print collate with word or some other product.  This confirms no os or printer driver update has introduced a new problem., On a windows 7, switch over to pcl or other driver and see if still have issue.

Comment: With other products no problem printing in collate. There is no PCL driver for Windows 7 from the Canon manufacturer for this model of printer. With other model canon printer with PCL driver, print without problems in collate. We think the problem is in Windows because this issue happened last week. Maybe some update messed it.

Comment: Take an empty excel file. Copy and paste each sheet over using ctrl-a, ctrl-c (This gets all the data on a sheet) thenAtl-E-S-V in the destination. If the tabs have been renamed, then rename the tabs in the blank sheet. Close original, and save new as Test or someother name. Then reboot, open test and print.  IF this cleans things up then there is an embedded issue.

Comment: PS, the alt E-S-V is dropping formatting, do not worry if it looks slightly different or dates/times do not display correct.  This is just a test to find where the issue lies